# custom htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

we have urls as;

```
 - mydomain.com/my-keyword/
 - mydomain.com/my-other-keyword/
 - mydomain.com/my-another-keyword/
```

and also

```
 - mydomain.com/my-keyword/a-page.html
 - mydomain.com/my-keyword/another-page.html
 - mydomain.com/my-other-keyword/some-page.html
 - mydomain.com/my-other-keyword/any-page.html
 - mydomain.com/my-another-keyword/another-page.html
 - mydomain.com/my-another-keyword/some-page.html
```

We want to convert (301) all urls created without `/` for example; `mydomain.com/my-another-keyword` -> to -> `mydomain.com/my-another-keyword/` without harming the rest of the url structure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

if the file exists: dont add slash, if it's not a file: add slash

Comment: this would NOT work, because we dont have a files with those names. Basically our original rewrite can rewrite anything regardless of what address is called as long as keyword exists. It will pull out the details and print them on page.

    mydomain.com/colorado-hotels/ or
    mydomain.com/colorado_hotel/

They both bring out the same data.
So obviously **mydomain.com/colorado_hotel** will also work.
Thanks but, this is why yours is no good.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you as long as a "directory" in the path does not contain a .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```